# 1:M relationship in Hibernate and cascading operations

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, cascade

Table SUBCOURSE references COURSE
COURSE(id, name)
SUBCOURSE(id, course_id, name)

So, 1:M.

Hibernate generates for Course:

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "course", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set getSubCourses() {
        return this.subCourses;
    }
```

for Subcourse it generates

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", nullable = false)
    public Course getCourse() {
        return this.course;
    }
```

Now the problem is that cascading does not work as expected.
I want to create a collection of SubCourse objects (Set), fill it and then
bind it to setSubCourses() of Course object. Then simply persist the Course object.

Though, having ManyToOne thing in a Subcourses table, I need to manually
setCourse() before adding to collection on each object. If I do not do so,
an exception is raised when persisting Course object with its collection.

What can you recommend me?

P.S. or maybe this is part of the game? setting a parent object of every child by hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this is part of the game. Quote from the Hibernate book (referring to an example where `Item` is the parent and `Bid` is the child):

> If you only call `anItem.getBids().add(bid)`, no changes are made persistent!
>   You get what you want only if the other side, `aBid.setItem(anItem)`, is set correctly.
>   This is consistent with the behavior in Java without Hibernate: If an association
>   is bidirectional, you have to create the link with pointers on two sides, not just
>   one. It’s the primary reason why we recommend convenience methods such as
>   `addBid()` — they take care of the bidirectional references in a system without container-
>   managed relationships.

The class referred to above is

```
public class Item {
  ...
  private Set bids = new HashSet();
  public void setBids(Set bids) {
    this.bids = bids;
  }
  public Set getBids() {
    return bids;
  }
  public void addBid(Bid bid) {
    bid.setItem(this);
    bids.add(bid);
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with a bi-directional association, it is necessary to set **both** sides of the link correctly (as documented in [1.2.6. Working bi-directional links](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations-usingbidir)). I often use the defensive approach suggested in the documentation:

> Many developers program defensively
>   and create link management methods to
>   correctly set both sides (for example,
>   in `Person`):
>
> ```
> protected Set getEvents() {
>     return events;
> }
>
> protected void setEvents(Set events) {
>     this.events = events;
> }
>
> public void addToEvent(Event event) {
>     this.getEvents().add(event);
>     event.getParticipants().add(this);
> }
>
> public void removeFromEvent(Event event) {
>     this.getEvents().remove(event);
>     event.getParticipants().remove(this);
> }
> ```
>
> The get and set methods for the
>   collection are now protected. This
>   allows classes in the same package and
>   subclasses to still access the
>   methods, but prevents everybody else
>   from altering the collections
>   directly. Repeat the steps for the
>   collection on the other side.